# How to count value of a specific time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `company` (columns `id`, `name`) and `post` (columns `id`, `company_id`, `created`). If I want to count the number of posts for a certain period, how should I write my query?

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,count(p1.id)
FROM company c
JOIN (SELECT id, company_id, min(created) as startday, max(created) as endday from post) p
JOIN (select id, company_id, created from post) p1
ON p1.company_id=c.id and p1.created > endday and p1.created < startday
GROUP BY c.id
```

for example,

company

```
----------
id | name
-----------
 1 |   a
 2 |   b
 3 |   c    
-------------
```

post

```
------
id|company_id|created
 1|  1       | 2017-01
 2|  1       | 2017-02
 3|  1       | 2017-02
 4|  2       | 2-17-01
---------
```

I want to get a result like this

```
company|id|startday|endday|count
    a  |1 |    
    b  |2 |
    c  |3 |
```

Comment: Please provide example data from the tables companty and post and expected output..

Comment: I edited my question. but the format changed. is that clear for you ?

Comment: it's clear i think ive posted a answer